# Asset prices vs. Asset pricing?

Tags: discussion

How do these two tags differ?

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asset-pricing

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asset-prices

Answer (score 1):

The tag asset pricing has its own summary:

> The branch of Finance that studies and models how specific assets (such as options, bonds and stocks) are priced.

The tag asset prices just refers to asset prices.